# Is the function that maps a matrix to the determinant of a submatrix continuous?

Tags: matrices, continuity, determinant

Let $M$ be the space of $m \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.
For each $A$ in $M$ let $A'$ be a fixed submatrix of $A$. 
Is the function $M \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $A \mapsto \det(A')$ continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a polynomial in (some of) the entries of $A$.